Making sure that a citation always has the same number
I know this will sound quite weird. However I can assure you that I have a very good (easter-egg related) reason to do this.
I would like a certain hidden citation - i.e. not shown in the text - to have a specific number, and still appear in the bibliographic references. For instance let say I want citation [2] in the following example to always appear as [2] no matter what the code actually looks like.
Here is a MWE with the second work of John Doe labeled [2]:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none, style=numeric-comp, backref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{my_bib.bib}
@article{citationA,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "First work",
    year    = "1990",
    journal = "some journal"
}

@article{citationB,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "Second work",
    year    = "1990",
    journal = "some journal"
}

@article{citationC,
    author  = "John Doe",
    title   = "Third work",
    year    = "1990",
    journal = "some journal"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{my_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

This is numbered one\cite{citationA}.\nocite{citationB}

This is numbered three\cite{citationC}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

which most conveniently produces:

However, if I add another citation at the end of the first line, the "second work" is now labelled [3], i.e. if I replace line:
This is numbered one\cite{citationA}.\nocite{citationB}

by
This is numbered one\cite{citationA, citationC}.\nocite{citationB}

I now get this result:


My question is thus: is there a way to force biblatex / biber to always assign a specific number to a given (hidden) citation entry?
In the afore-presented example, this would be asking for the "Second work" to always be numbered [2], no matter what cite commands are actually used in the text.
BONUS: If it were also possible for this hidden entry to have a custom text for the "cit. on p. XXX" (i.e. a custom "XXX" text), it would be absolutely perfect.

Very broadly related (but the approach there does not help here at all - for the question here we need to influence sorting, which the code discussed over there cannot do): https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1360

If you know it's always the second citation (and you also know what #1 is), then \nocite{citationA,citationB} in the preamble will do this.

@karlh, in practice, it's not the second one (think several hundreds, it's in a book with over 700 references, about midway). Let's call this number N, I could make a Python program to parse the LaTeX code, get all citations in order of appearance, and add a nocite command with the N-1 first ones at the beginning of the document, adding in N position the citation I want to hide. I might end up actually doing this, but it's not very LaTeX-ic ^^"

@mranvick It is an option, if a potentially labor-intensive one, to edit the .bbl file, identify which citation is the "correct" one, then insert the "hidden" one at that point. Running Biber again will destroy that file, however, hence the labor-intensive part.
